# Edit suggestion wrongly approved

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I was just going through some edit suggestions, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2806354) got approved by some pretty new reviewers who've been approving everything. It seems to me it's pretty clearly an attempt to comment or answer, but either way is taking too much liberty with the question. Am I wrong? Is meta the place to mention this?

EDIT: Never mind. I didn't notice it was approved by the OP.

Comment: The OP approved it, so it's not really wrong. Also, the two variables weren't used, so I guess it was right to remove it.

Comment: @DaveChen I didn't even notice that. Whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably would have rejected it as well, but given that the edit was approved by the original poster, it appears that this was indeed in line with the original question.

The edit did not deface the question or dramatically alter it in a way that invalidates the answers. It simply removes some unused variables. As I said, I'd probably reject the edit, but in this case I would not definitely not roll it back.

Answer (score 3):

The edit removes two unused variables from the code in the question.  It is borderline 'too minor' — but I don't think the edit is erroneous.  As such, it doesn't seem to need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If an edit is approved that is 'wrong', then go back in and fix it yourself.  (As opposed to just 'too minor' which I would leave alone.)

Comment: Doesn't this type of behavior lead to editing wars?

Comment: Even though you rollback, the editor still gets the 2 rep, no?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: yes, they get the rep; that isn't the end of the world.  They don't get educated on the review process — that's a little unfortunate, but the edit was correct, if minor, so that too is not the end of the world.  BenjaminRH: editing and edit can lead to editing wars, but this really isn't controversial as a change and shouldn't manage to lead to a war.  The edit was correct; what was arguably incorrect was anyone getting the rep for making the change.

Comment: @Jonathan that's my point. A rollback should revoke the rep.

Comment: The rollback can be done by anyone without review; the rep was gained after 3 people agreed with the proposed edit (and 2 did not).